# Extrapolate Linear Regression

Tags: excel, math, regression

I am new with excel, but how can i get an estimate for the values in 2013 of something like this:

[image: Excel image]

I need an estimate which is the extrapolation of the value according to the linear regression the counterparts observed in recent years.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer this, I plotted data in two ways: (a) showing each year separately, and (b) showing all the data as one line through time.  The graphs are as follows:

[image: Data with each year plotted separately]

[image: All data on one line]

Looking at the first graph, if there is any [seasonality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seasonality) in the data, it's not very strong.  However, looking at all the data plotted on one line through time, it looks as though there is an upward trend.  So my suggestion is to do the most basic regression and fit a straight line to the data.  The graph with the trend line added is as follows:

[image: All data on one line, plus trend line]

In numbers, the results are:

```
               Data        Best fit straight line
Jan-10          218          232.7
Feb-10          251          235.0
Mar-10          221          237.1
Apr-10          241          239.4
May-10          261          241.7
Jun-10          227          244.0
Jul-10          253          246.3
Aug-10          266          248.6
Sep-10          238          250.9
Oct-10          255          253.2
Nov-10          238          255.5
Dec-10          219          257.7
Jan-11          263          260.0
Feb-11          239          262.4
Mar-11          255          264.5
Apr-11          297          266.8
May-11          299          269.0
Jun-11          256          271.4
Jul-11          292          273.6
Aug-11          247          275.9
Sep-11          254          278.2
Oct-11          258          280.5
Nov-11          264          282.8
Dec-11          301          285.1
Jan-12          319          287.4
Feb-12          314          289.7
Mar-12          274          291.9
Apr-12          325          294.2
May-12          319          296.4
Jun-12          339          298.8
Jul-12          339          301.0
Aug-12          271          303.3
Sep-12          310          305.7
Oct-12          291          307.9
Nov-12          259          310.2
Dec-12          286          312.5
Jan-13                       314.8
Feb-13                       317.1
Mar-13                       319.2
Apr-13                       321.5
May-13                       323.8
Jun-13                       326.1
Jul-13                       328.4
Aug-13                       330.7
Sep-13                       333.0
Oct-13                       335.2
Nov-13                       337.6
Dec-13                       339.8
```

Answer (score 2):

There are different ways you can apply linear regression. You could, for example, use all your data points to create an equation to calculate for all the subsequent months. However, if there are yearly cycles, you might just want to use the data for each January to estimate the next January; each month of February to estimate February; etc. To keep it simple, let's just work with January for now. In order to keep the numbers smaller, I'm just going to use the last two digits of the year:

```
X       Y
10      218
11      263
12      319
```

Next calculate 4 different sums:

```
S[x] = Sum of all Xs = 33
S[y] = Sum of all Ys = 800
S[xx] = Sum of X squared = 100 + 121 + 144 = 365
S[xy] = Sum of X*Y = 2180 + 2893 + 3828 = 8901
```

Calculate slope and intercept:

```
N = Number of data points sampled = 3
M = Slope = (N*S[xy] - S[x]*S[y])/(N*S[xx] - S[x]^2)
M = (3*8901 - 33*800)/(3*365 - 33^2) = 303/6 = 50.5
B = Intercept = (S[y] - M*S[x])/N
B = (800 - 50.5*33)/3 = -866.5/3 = -289
```

Therefore the equation for January would be:

```
Y = M*X + B
Y = 50.5*X - 289
```

Calculate for the year 2013:

```
Y = 50.5*13 -289 = 368
```

Answer (score 1):

Start by plotting your data.  Decide what kind of function will be a good fit.

You can either create a fit for each month or try to create one that has both year and month as independent variables.

Let's assume that a polynomial fit for each month will work for you:

```
y = c0 + c1*m + c2*m^2
```

So for January:

```
218 = c0 + c1*2010 + c2*2010^2
263 = c0 + c1*2011 + c2*2011^2 
319 = c0 + c1*2012 + c2*2012^2
```

So now you have three equations for three unknowns.  Solve for `(c0, c1, c2)` and the substitute `m = 2013` for your extrapolation.

Here are the results I get:

```
Month   2010    2011    2012    2013
1           218 263 319 386
2           251 239 314 476
3           221 255 274 278
4           241 297 325 325
5           261 299 319 321
6           227 256 339 476
7           253 292 339 394
8           266 247 271 338
9           238 254 310 406
10          255 258 291 354
11          238 264 259 223
12          219 301 286 174
```

See how you do.